# How to remove objects that have 3 properties the same only leaving 1 but adding the number of those duplicates to a nr. column of that 1

Tags: c#, linq

I have a txt file of over a 100k rows with values like this.

A B C D 1 2

A B C E 1 3

D E C F 1 3

D E C F 1 3

A B C B 1 2

E F G G 1 1

I read the file and fill an object with it and then add it into a list but what I need to do next is take the values that have certain properties the same summing one number column which always has a value 1 for those rows with those repeating values. So in the example i would get a list with objects like so

A B C 3 6

D E C 2 6

E F G 1 1

There are 3 A B C values so I leave only one and the number is really the sum but also the count since that value is always 1. The other columns are different but irrelevant to me if the 3 I look at are the same then I consider the object to be the same.One way I have found to do the grouping is using LINQ and group by with a key and if I also create a counter I also get a count of every value (which is the sum since the number is always 1) however this does not give me what I need.

Is there any way using LINQ after the group by to get this effect? Or another method?

**EDIT**

My Latest attempt

```
 var dupes = serijskaLista.GroupBy(e => new { e.sreIsplatio, e.sreIznDob, e.sreSif, e.sreSerija })           
            .Select(y => new { Element = y.Key, Counter = y.Count()});

            ConcurrentBag<SreckaIsplacena> sgmooreList = new ConcurrentBag<SreckaIsplacena>();
           

            List<Srecka> _srecke = _glavniRepository.UcitajSamoaktivneSrecke().OrderByDescending(item => item.ID).ToList<Srecka>();
          ConcurrentBag<SreckaIsplacena> pomList = new ConcurrentBag<SreckaIsplacena>();
          SreckaIsplacena _isplacena;
          SreckaNagrade nag;
            
          Parallel.ForEach(dupes, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 }, (dp) =>
            {
                    Srecka srec = (from s in _srecke
                                 where s.Sifra == dp.Element.sreSif && s.Serija == dp.Element.sreSerija
                                 select s).First();
                    ConcurrentBag<SreckaNagrade> sreckaNagrade = new ConcurrentBag<SreckaNagrade>(_glavniRepository.DohvatiNagradeZaSrecku(srec.ID));
                   
                if (sreckaNagrade != null)
                { 
                     nag = (from sn in sreckaNagrade
                                         where sn.Iznos == dp.Element.sreIznDob
                                         select sn).FirstOrDefault();

                     Odobrenje odo = new Odobrenje();
                     odo = odo.DohvatiOdobrenje(valutaGlavna.ID, dp.Element.sreIsplatio).FirstOrDefault();

                    if (odo != null)
                    { 
                     ConcurrentBag<PorezSrecka> listaPoreza = new ConcurrentBag<PorezSrecka>(_glavniRepository.UcitajPorezSrecka(valutaGlavna, odo, srec, nag.NagradaId));

                     _isplacena = new SreckaIsplacena();
                     decimal iz = Convert.ToDecimal(dp.Element.sreIznDob);
                     _isplacena.BrojDobitaka = dp.Counter;
                     _isplacena.Iznos = iz;
                     _isplacena.Nagrada = nag;
                     _isplacena.Prodavac = dp.Element.sreIsplatio;
                     _isplacena.Valuta = valutaGlavna;
                     _isplacena.Srecka = srec;                         
                     _isplacena.Cijena = Convert.ToDecimal(srec.Cijena);
                    
                     if (listaPoreza.Count == 1)
                     {
                         PorezSrecka ps = listaPoreza.ElementAt(0);
                         _isplacena.SreckaPorez = ps;
                     }
                     lock (_isplacena)
                     {
                         _isplacena.Save();

                         lock (pomList)
                         {
                             pomList.Add(_isplacena);
                         }
                     }

                    }
                     
                }
    
                });
```

What happens is this seems to insert correctly into the DB but the ConcurrentBag is not filled correctly. I don't understand why

Comment: are there cases with overlapping properties like `A B C D` and `B C D E`?

Comment: Show us your LINQ query.

Comment: Why A B C 3 6 rather than A B C 3 7 ?

Comment: @hubo Not sure what you exactly mean by overlapping they may have same values but they are not the same properties the main ones are these 3 that determine if the row is "unique" for my purposes.

Comment: @sgmoore it is not really relevant but in the real code one of the column is multiplied by the summed column. so 3 x 2 is 6 but again this is outside the scope of my question

Answer (score 0):

This does **not** give you the results you desire, as I don't know how the last number is calculated, and you say the actual calculation of the last number is outside the scope the question.

So, as an example, I will use a calculation of doubling the maximum of the last number in the input group. You will need to replace that with the actual calculation.

e.g.

```
string text= @"
A B C D 1 2
A B C E 1 3
D E C F 1 3
D E C F 1 3
A B C B 1 2
E F G G 1 1
";

// Split into lines and then by spaces to get data which can be queried.

var data = text.Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n'} , StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(l=>l.Split(new char[] { ' '}))
        .Select(a => new 
            { 
            L1 = a[0], L2 = a[1], L3 = a[2], L4 = a[3], 
            N1 = Convert.ToInt32(a[4]), 
            N2 = Convert.ToInt32(a[5])
            }
        );

// Group by the first three letters
// and calculate the numeric values for each group
var grouped = (from r in data group r by r.L1 + " "+ r.L2 + " " + r.L3 into results 
                select new 
                {
                    results.Key, 
                    N1 = results.Sum(a=>a.N1) ,     // or N1 = results.Count() ,
                    N2 = results.Max(a=>a.N2) * 2   // Replace with actual calculation
                }
            );
            
grouped.Dump();

// Or if you want it export back to text
var text2 = String.Join("\r\n", grouped.Select(a => $"{a.Key} {a.N1} {a.N2}"));

text2.Dump();
```

Results in LinqPad would be

[image]

Comment: I think I phrased my question badly. The issue is that I need to make these changes on the original object. Your solution creates a new object with these key elements and a sum (or counter) that gives me the correct information but how do I then put that information into the original list with all the data removing the duplicate objects and changing the n1 property on the object from 1 (because its always 1) to the number from your solution?

Comment: I don't think your updated question is any clearer and in particular it is not clear to me why would need to update the existing objects in the original list rather than create a new List. You really need to produce a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You can create a new list if it is of the same type as my original list. The issue is that there is one more column that is wholly unique but if I add it to key then the grouping won't work because it is unique for every row. But I need the grouping while also needing that column. Writing this I realize I sound like the mad hatter.

Comment: Please check my latest edit if you can @sgmoore

Comment: Sorry, but I really have no idea what you are trying to do.